# MongoDB upgrade on Ubuntu causing "Low Disk Space" error message

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I am trying to upgrade MongoDB from version 1.6.5 to version 2.0.1 on an Ubuntu machine. I have tried many ways of updating, including replacing the binaries with the more recent ones, to adding mongodb-10gen to my sources list and installing from apt-get. However, each time I start mongodb after the upgrade I get a message similar to the following from the OS:

This computer has only 176.0 KB disk space remaining.
You can free up disk space by removing unused programs or files, or by moving files to an external disk.

I am confident that I have more than enough space for this upgrade, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong for this to continue happening. Anyone run across similar issues? Were you able to solve it?

---

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             7.5G  7.2G   64K 100% /
none                  492M  216K  492M   1% /dev
none                  499M  184K  499M   1% /dev/shm
none                  499M  144K  499M   1% /var/run
none                  499M     0  499M   0% /var/lock
none                  4.0T     0  4.0T   0% /media/psf
/dev/sr0               23M   23M     0 100% /media/CDROM
```

Comment: can you provide the output of df -h?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running a 64-bit system?  Journaling is automatically enabled on 64-bit systems as of Mongo 1.9.2, and this can take up quite a bit of space.  You can safely disable journaling and clear out the old journal files (which can be quite big).

To disable from config file, you will need to COMMENT OUT or DELETE the line that says `journal = true` (if it exists) and add a line that says `nojournal = true`.  Or, if you're running Mongo via command line, specify `--nojournal`.  Regardless, make sure you restart Mongo before going to the next step.

To delete the journal files, go to your `{dbpath}/journal` and remove the entire `journal` subdirectory.  This will clear out the journal files and should clean up quite a bit of space.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I am running a 64-bit system, and that looks like it was totally the problem. I am testing this in a VM that doesn't have a ton of disk space, but should have had enough, when I did what you said, it freed up a ton of space. Thanks!

Comment: No problem; I only knew because I ran into the same exact issue!  Glad you got it all resolved! :)

Comment: This answer has just saved my life! Thanks @nicknisi